# Percentage deviation statistics in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Say I want to compute the following four statistics of my groups in a Dataframe in Pandas:

```
% of points in the group that are > X higher (or X lower) than the median
```

for the following values of `X`: `10%, 25%, 50%` and `75%`.

Is there a built-in aggregation function (either in Pandas or numpy) that gives these types of statistics?

They are somehow related to [percentiles](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html), but not quite the same. The `qth` percentile of a vector V of length N is the **qth ranked value** in a sorted copy of V, which is different from what I am describing above.

Does this statistic have a name?

Comment: Not sure if it has a specific name, but can't you do this with numpy's [percentileofscore](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html#scipy.stats.percentileofscore) function? So, for the 10% case, you want `1 - percentileofscore(data,data.median()*1.1)`

Comment: Thanks @KarlD. That's a great pointer. I think you are right, I should be able to do it using that function